# Any way to change a character's race?

Tags: starbound

In Starbound, is there a way to change a player's race? I am using a modded race, and want to switch off of it.

I want to keep my current character, as I don't want to go through the quests and story again, along with re-earning everything I have.

Comment: I assume you mean during the game/playthrough of current character?

Comment: Are you willing to start a new character, but keep your items, etc..?

Comment: @Oak yeah, Ill add that to the question.

Comment: @n_palum yeah, ill add it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the numerous responses in threads like [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/211820/discussions/0/353915309336813404/) or [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/app/211820/discussions/0/352788917760461970/), as well as from personal experience, there is no way to change your character's race after creating it, unfortunately.

Since your race is tied to your ship, it would likely create issues if you attempted to mod the game in order to allow racial changes, too.

Your best bet would be to create a new character and transfer your items, though I realize this is less than ideal.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say. You *can* transfer items but it's tedious.

Comment: @n_palum and even then, you gotta redo the quests and upgrades, which isnt fun. ill keep searching, though i am afraid this is the only answer

Comment: Yup, that's a pretty common them across many games - at least RPGs